# How can I create ProgressBar in notification in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, uilocalnotification, unnotificationserviceextension

Is there Any way to implement a Progressbar in ios to show it is something is Uploading or Downloading in Local Notification I have referred.

```
Notification Service Extension
```

and

```
Notification Content Extension
```

So is there any way to implement the progress view in any of this...I am New to iOS Development

Comment: I need same thing in my application, have you get any lead?

Answer (score -1):

## UIProgressView

```
UIProgressView *progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleDefault];
[self.view addSubview:progressView];
[progressView setProgress:0.5 animated:YES];
```